# MVC 5 Cascading DropDownList Bootstrap selectpicker - empty list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am not a frontend guy but I have to do something.
I have two lists:

- showTeam
- showMember - cascading based on showTeam.

In my HTML source code I see all the items placed as `option`, but when I click the DropDownList I see 0 items to pick. If I remove the selectpicker all items are visible. Any help is appreciated.

```
@Html.DropDownList("showTeams", null, "-Select Team-", htmlAttributes: new { id = "ddshowTeams", @class = "selectCountry selectpicker show-tick form-control" })
                                              @Html.DropDownList("showMembers", null, "-Select Team-", htmlAttributes: new { id = "ddshowMembers", @class = " selectCountry selectpicker show-tick form-control" })
```

Ajax call:

```
      debugger;
      $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $("#ddshowTeams").change(function () {
            alert("pehla andar");
            $("#ddshowMembers").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetListLabels","CTComparer")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#ddshowTeams").val() },
                success: function (mems) {
                    console.log("which ayaeee");
                    // states contains the JSON formatted list
                    // of states passed from the controller
                 

                    $.each(mems, function (i, member) {

                        //alert('<option value="'
                        //    + member.Value + '">'
                        //    + member.Text + '</option>');

                        $("#ddshowMembers").append('<option value="'
+ member.Value + '">'
+ member.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
        });
```

Json method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetListLabels(int id)
    {
        var list = GetLabelList(id)
                         .Select(p =>
                                   new SelectListItem
                                   {
                                       Value = "",
                                       Text = p.Name
                                   });
      //  this.ViewBag.SourceLabels = this.GetListLabelsSelectedItems(id);
      //  this.ViewData["showMembers"] = this.GetListLabelsSelectedItems(0);
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: can you put action to get list team and your model for team and member?

Comment: First, you have to bind your ShowTeam dropdown with view bag team's list or model object then after you will pick a team from showteam dropdown and based on the selected team you will get member list.

Comment: If you go into Dev tools and put a debugger in your Ajax success, can you see any value in `mems`?